# 9 month old watching Telly

Tags: toddler, television, screen-time

My 9 month old daughter seems to have got a great liking for ABC Videos and nursery rhymes from  youtube.

Lately she has been watching these ABC Videos and rhymes continuously for couple of hrs! She seems to be completely lost in the TV and reacts actively when she sees these videos

We have got a big Panasonic plasma TV with natural colours and she is watching from a distance so I am not sure her eyes were strained or not.

Is there anything to worry about? Some people say that she should not be watching the telly at all while others say it is good for her and she would absorb the knowledge naturally.

Comment: We have various questions here on this topic, and they all agree that while television is enjoyable, the single most important thing you can do is interact with your child yourself. Hours of television will potentially impact conversation, relationships etc

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/is-it-too-dangerous-for-my-2-years-old-son-to-watch-youtube-on-the-ipad-for-hour?rq=1

Comment: Possibly interesting for some background and some links (2nd answer): http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/20033/why-does-2-hours-in-front-of-the-tv-make-my-kids-grumpy/20034#20034

Comment: For more questions on the subject, see the *television* tag. I added it to your question, simply click on the tag. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

The medical community [discourages passive screen time before two](http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2013/10/29/228125739/what-to-know-about-babies-and-screen-time-kids-screens-electronics).

And of course she's engaged for a couple hours. Flashing screens with beautiful colors and music are fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

All the medical advice says nothing is better for your kiddo than interaction with an adult.

The approach we try to take in our home is "what is this displacing?" Maybe to a lesser extent we worry about "what habit is this building?" Because nothing at all before two is a great goal to have that may run up against reality in ugly ways. My wife and I need to cook and clean and do other things that help us keep body and soul united. So while it's lovely to think that time my son doesn't spend watching tv is personal interaction time, the reality is that I can't always be interacting with him.

So as early as one our kid was allowed various amounts of videos. We avoided things with frenetic action and a lot of blinky-blinky and aimed for more informative/educational stuff. Animal videos, animation targeted at younger kids like AlphaBlocks, etc. We committed to not turning to it at the slightest request/difficulty, so sometimes boyo asks for tv or ipad and we have to stick it out a bit before he turns to playing with his trains or other toys.

Personally I think "hours" is a lot of veg time, but I don't much like to just sit and stare at a screen for that long myself. If it's something that she won't turn away from to do physical things then I think that can be a problem. I don't think you should make perfect the enemy of good - if you need some segments of time to do some other things then by all means, some video entertainment is okay. But you also shouldn't fool yourself that extended period of time motionless in front of the tube is displacing physical activity she needs to be engaging in on her way to walking and improving her physical dexterity.